# How to set initial size in WPF Window docked in DockPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, sizetocontent

I want to set initial size of `listview`. `ListView` is docked in `DockPanel` as a last child with property LastChildFill = true. The Window has SizeToContent set to SizeToContent.Height.
I want Window to change size as user resizes it and I want ListView to change its size respectively. 
But I'd like ListView height is 200 as Window opens.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, calculate the window height needed when the listbox is 200. Then simply set the height of the window to that number like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="200" Height="225"
        Title="MainWindow" >
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">Other text</TextBlock>
        <ListView BorderBrush="Orange" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

If this is not possible, (eg you don't know in advance the size of the other elements), then do the following:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="200" SizeToContent="Height"
        Title="MainWindow" Loaded="Window_Loaded" >
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">Other Text</TextBlock>
        <ListView BorderBrush="Orange" Name="listbox" Height="200" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

and in code behind:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Height = ActualHeight;
    SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.Manual;
    listbox.Height = Double.NaN;
}
```

Comment: Second solution with mininal adjustment works for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="640" SizeToContent="Height"
        Title="MainWindow" Loaded="Window_Loaded" >
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">Other Text</TextBlock>
        <ListView Name="listbox" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

and in code behind:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.Manual;
    Height = 480;
}
```